# Create a temporary users on ubuntu

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, delete, time, adduser

- I want to create a temporary user on ubuntu that gets deleted within a certain period of time.
- I can extend the deletion time.
- I can get the value of the remaining time for the user before deletion.
  and thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a temporary user with the help of `useradd` command and `--expiredate` option (expiry date) that is disabled/expired after a certain period of time.

```
sudo useradd -e <date> username  # or
sudo useradd --expiredate <date> username
```

Suppose you want to create a user `test` and set the expiry time to '01 January 2023'.

```
sudo useradd -e 2023-01-01 test
```

You can then verify the expiry date etc

```
sudo chage -l test
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead

Comment: I have edited the code

Comment: Thank you for that, but I also meant the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Following your three points, but split into more atomic actions:

#### 1. Create or update user

Create a user with expiry date, or modify a user.  Note: use `YYYY-MM-DD` date-format.

Creating newuser:

```bash
sudo useradd -e 2022-12-31 newuser
```

Modifying existinguser:

```bash
sudo chage --expiredate 2022-12-31 existinguser
```

#### 2. Find expiry date

In short, the entire process is packaged in a file, but below are the key pieces of the process, explained.

```bash
chage --list --iso8601 test | grep "Account expires" | sed -s 's/.*:\ //g'
```

The command `chage` requires root priviledges.  The argument `iso8601` keeps the date the same regardless of locale in your session.
The `sed` substitutes `s` all characters until the first occurance of `:`  (note the space bar), which leaves us with the date (formated exactly like the output of `date '+%F'` command).

#### 3. Chron-automated user removal

Let us automate that.  Assume that the file `/root/remove-expired-users.sh` contains the following code.

```bash
#/bin/bash

SOURCEURL='[https://askubuntu.com/questions/1445285/create-a-temporary-users-on-ubuntu]'
LOGFILE='/var/log/messages'

for USERNAME in $(sed 's/\:.*$//g' /etc/passwd); do

    echo "`date '+%F_%R'` :: $SOURCEURL :: Testing user -=## $USERNAME ##=- against being expired, for removal." >> $LOGFILE
    EXPIRYDATE=`chage --list --iso8601 $USERNAME | grep "Account expires" | sed -s 's/.*:\ //g'`

    if [ `date '+%F'` = $EXPIRYDATE ]; then

        echo "`date '+%F_%R'` :: $SOURCEURL :: User -=## $USERNAME ##=- expired today. Remove action commented-out for safety." >> $LOGFILE

        # deluser $USERNAME
        # deluser --group --only-if-empty $USERNAME

    fi

done
```

Make `/root/remove-expired-users.sh` executable at least for root, add this line: `14 3 * * * /root/remove-expired-users.sh` to root's crontab (here: `sudo -i crontab -e`) in order to have users expired today removed at 3:14 in the morning (although it makes more sense to remove them at 23:59).

**Comments:**

- This is not elegant (and not safe) to list the entire `/etc/passwd`, but will do for learninig.  For prod this loop shall exclude users with id below 1000, or even more (like admins too).
- User removal is commented-out for safety.  Make sure you test at a re-spawn-able virtual machine, or else you are asking for problems.
- Most of these actions require root, and hence needs to be configured on root's cron.  Moreover, with great power (of root) comes a great responsibility: misspellings, can be disastrous.
- If your machine is not running on a particular day, at a time the script shall be run, the users with the current-day expiry-date will remain not deleted in the system.  Which violates the assumptions, but on the other hand they are already unable to log in.

#### 4. Number of days till expiry

There is a command above for viewing the expiry date.  Number of days till expiry could be calculated by the following steps:

- Convert expiry date and today's date to (mili)seconds since epoch.
- Do subtraction of these.  Anything numerical and non-negative (or positive, depending on what you subtract from what) qualifies for the following step.
- Divide and round as appropriate in order to obtain days and hours till expiry.